# No values in web scraping?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

i'm a new coder and i've run into som issues with my web scraping project.
My code:

```
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB?p=FB')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text,"lxml")

soup.find_all('div')
```

When I run the code in PyCharm i get dom't get any errors, i just dont get any values at all. I have watched several tutorials on how to web scrape using bs4 and Requests, but this frustrates me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why import bs4 twice?

Comment: It is giving result. Just try to print the values of soup.find_all('div'). something like this 
result = soup.find_all('div')
print(result)